# What is the difference between the Amazon S3 API calls GetObject and GetObjectRequest?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am new to the Amazon S3 API and I am attempting to build a client using Go. I was confused about how I would go about writing a Get function to get an object from an S3 bucket. The documentation for the API calls are a little confusing to me, I am wondering what is the difference between using the GetObject call vs the GetObjectRequest call? And when is it appropriate to use one over the other?

Comment: Which version of SDK are you using ? Could you please provide links to documentation where calls are described ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/making-requests.html#get-http-request-response):

> Calling the request form of a service operation, which follows the naming pattern OperationName Request, provides a simple way to control when a request is built, signed, and sent. Calling the request form immediately returns a request object. The request object output is a struct pointer that is not valid until the request is sent and returned successfully.

So, use `GetObject` if you want to immediately send the request and wait for the response. Use `GetObjectRequest` if you prefer to construct the request but not send it till later.

For most scenarios, you'd probably just use `GetObject`.